# Is there any wat to make GUI of graph data structure in any language?

Tags: user-interface, data-structures

I want to implement graph data structure and want to make its graphical view in any language like Windows form or java any one. If you know about it then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Tall order.

When I was learning data-structures I always found this page to be helpful for understanding data structures.

https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Algorithms.html

This has a  bunch of different types of graphs if you scroll down.
The javascript version of each visualization is still maintained. **Maybe you can use this as a point of departure and try to reverse engineer whatever specific graph algorithm you are trying to construct.**